# is there a method to make a struct inside another struct take less then one byte?

Tags: c, gcc, bit-fields

Hi I'm defining a chip instruction, and would like to use bit-field so it is easy to operate.

The instruction may looks like the following:

```c
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) Opcode {
    enum {
        OP_CLASS1 = 0,
        OP_CLASS2 = 1,
        OP_CLASS3 = 2
    } opcode_class:2;
    union __attribute__((__packed__)) {
        struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
            enum {
                sub1_1 = 0,
                sub1_2 = 1,
                sub1_3 = 2,
                sub1_4 = 3
            } sub1:2;
            enum {
                sub2_1 = 0,
                sub2_1 = 1
            } sub2:2;
            enum {
                sub3_1 = 0,
                sub3_2  = 1,
                sub3_4 = 2
            } sub3:2; 
        } class1;
        struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
            enum {
                sub1_1 = 0,
                sub1_2 = 1,
            } sub1:3;
            unsigned char un_use:3;
        } class2;
        struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
            enum {
                sub1_1 = 0,
                sub1_2 = 0,
                sub1_3 = 0,
                sub1_4 = 0,
            } sub1:2;
            unsigned char un_use:4;
        } class3;
        unsigned char un_use:6;
    } opcode_ext;
};
```

I hope it will be continues in memory for bit, so in total it will take 1 byte. However the result seems to be that 2 struct will take 1 byte each.

I would like to ask if there is a way that I can keep the hierarchical structure of the definition and make it continues in bit in c compiled by gcc?

Comment: Even an empty structure, one without any members, takes at least one byte of space. Since a byte is the least addressable unit in the system, that's what will be the smallest type.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude thanks, so is it better to define macros and using "and", "or“” logic operator with functions to do that??

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, standard C does not allow empty structures

Comment: @Shore Even using logical operators and bitfields/masks will still use at least 1 byte of memory since you have to store the intermediate value(s) of your calculation somewhere. As Some Programmer Dude mentioned, the smallest addressable size in a computer is a byte. Everything takes at least one byte.